# AJAX call to https endopint = secure?

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, cordova, https

I am planning a Cordova mobile application (a Meteor.js app to be precise) and I need to POST/GET some sensitive data from a remote server securely.

When the request is pointed at `https` endpoint is it secure? My guess is that it does not work this way.

Just to say - I have read some SO questions and searched google but most of them refer to CORS problems, which I am not facing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no

Sending data to a https server is secure?
Yes if you are sure that you are sending the data to your server

But, you might be connected to a public wifi, and somebody could be doing a man in the middle attack, so you think that you are sending your data to your sever, but the hacker is getting the data instead.

To avoid this, you can do server certificate pinning, there are a few plugins available, so you make sure the server where you are sending the data is really yours (comparing certificate fingerprint or checking some of the values)

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need. Https ([TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)) will provide your mobile users with the certainty that they are communicating with the server that is identified by the certificate. It will also encrypt the communication between the server and the mobile application so no one can listen in.

It won't authenticate your users and allow you to serve certain data to specific users only. You'd need some kind of authentication scheme for that.

It won't protect you from [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or other attacks either. So it very much depends on what your requirements are, but https by itself is not enough to protect a website.

Comment: I do understand most of the problems you have described. Since it is a mobile app the view is hosted on the client device (cordova) then i'm doing an ajax call to a https server endpoint. My question is if the communication between the client and the server is encrypted via the ssl certificate that the server has from the very beginning.

Comment: Not sure what the question is exactly. If that communication is secure? Yes, using http will secure the communication. Whether that is enough for your application depends on the other requirements as I mentioned in my answer.